# POST запрос более 5 минут после переноса сайта

Tags: php, javascript, post

НА тестовом домене и хостинге все работало отлично. Запрос проходил за пол секунды.

После переноса на домен и хостинг клиента запрос стал уходить очень долго. Максимальное время, которое я видел 7.5 минут.

Сделал скрин консоли и замер времени выполнения скрипта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код отправки формы скину если нужно, но он не менялся, поэтому думаю дело не в этом

Писать хостеру или все таки проблема на моей стороне? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `add.php` что делает?

Comment: Оставьте пустой add.php Запрос выполняется быстро? Если да, то возвращайте код кусками, пока не появится замедление. После этого думайте

Comment: Пустой уходит быстро, но не всегда. Буду дальше тестить

Comment: Была похожая проблема. Запрос висит минутами. Помогала только переустановка PHP. Не знаю почему.

Comment: Кто хостит? Нужно обращаться в поддержку!